# replace directory path to url path in mysql database table

Tags: mysql, url, path, directory, phpmyadmin

Dear all..before i give up after multiple trial and error attempts,can someone please help me with below query.

I am trying to replace the path name D:\Downloads\Music\ (note the slash) to http://mysite.com/Music/ in mysql field name called "filename" under "songlist" table.

Below is the query code that I tried ,but nothing happens.It only gives me the following message : 0 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.1428 sec )

**UPDATE songlist SET filename = replace(filename, "D:\Downloads\Music", "http://mysite.com/Music/")**

many thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the slashes. Check out the following as an example:

```
-- with escaping, yay it works
SELECT REPLACE(filename, 'D:\\Downloads\\Music', 'http://mysite.com/Music/') FROM songlist;
```

Comment: Jason, You are spot on !! Indeed that was the best answer. Thank you very much for the wonderful piece of code. Cheers - Neville

Comment: I'm assuming you are new to StackOverflow. If this worked, mark the answer with the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Hmnn!!! ran into issue again,the above query code executes correctly with the following message "Showing rows 0 - 29 (16,900 total, Query took 0.0005 sec)" but when i go back and click the table "songlist" it hasn't updated anything under the "filename".It still remains the ":D:\Downloads\Music". Any idea what may be the issue.

Comment: Nevermind...figured it out. Applied your comment "You need to escape the slashes" to my original code. Worked like a charm!!!.This is the final code : UPDATE songlist SET filename = replace(filename, "D:\\Downloads\\Music\\", "http://mysite.com/Music/") - Thanks for all your help Jason